# Rserve v.s. rpy

Tags: python, r, rpy2, rserve

I am working on a project pretty reliant on the use of statistics. It is mainly in Python, but I would like to use some bits of R in it, even if I am not well-off with R syntax and data structures. Thus I am hesitating between using an interface and I am hesitating [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html) and [Rserve](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/).

Which one would be more recommendable to begin with?

While reading some bits throughout the internet, I had an impression that Rserve is slightly better off then rpy, since it allows to use a separate server and had a more deep integration with python, but I haven't been able to find any more distinctions.

Comment: Totally, surprising I didn't find it at first